# Pandas column means comparisons

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

In Pandas Id like to compare mean of last 100 values from column to the entire column mean, basicly these values:
`value_x = df[['a','b']].tail(100).mean()` and
`value_y = df[['a','b']].mean()`
where column 'a' is True/False kind of identification.
Now I have `value_a` `value_b`, but not in the format I want.

The same for the next part: In the data I want to groupby value in column 'a' so it would look like this:
`value_x2 = df[['a','b']].tail(100).groupby(['a']).mean()` and
`value_y2 = df[['a','b']].groupby(['a']).mean()`

and from that I can get the "value" like this: `value_x3 = value_x2.loc['a_ID1']`, `value_y3 = value_y2.loc['a_ID1']`

My issue is that I can not compare these values, if I do

```
if value_x3 > value_y3: print('aaa') else: print('bbb')
```

I get ValueError: The truth value of Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I get the values to the correct format?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer myself.
Instead of using the previously mentioned way, I used simpler: `df[df['a_ID1']=='ID1'].b.mean()` for and the same with `.tail(100)`

If you have any better idea please share.
Thank you.